# Proxypac - Loadbalancing with "if(Math.random() < 0.5)"

Tags: java, proxy, load-balancing

We have 2 Proxy Servers and would like to loadbalance the traffic with the Proxypac. We are planing on implementing a loadbalancer to do this, but until then we want a better solution that manuall loadbalancing.

We would like to try this script, what do you guys think about this?

Thanks in advance

```
if(Math.random() < 0.5)
{
 return "PROXY 10.10.10.1:8080; " + "PROXY 10.10.10.2:8080";
}
else
{
 return "PROXY 10.10.10.2:8080; " + "PROXY 10.10.10.1:8080";
}
```

Comment: This is not really a programming question might be a better question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ (  conceptual questions) or http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ( peer programmer code reviews). Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As far as I know `Math.random()` doesn't spread the returned values steady.

Comment: `[Java]`, `If`, `Else` looks like programming to me. That would work however you may have runs where you get the same server time after time. why not just do a round robin with a simple counter and `if (counter%2`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind having approximate even distribution over a large number of requests, then your code will work fine.  But obviously, due to the randomness nature of your code, you could and will have moments where you keep hitting the same server over and over before you switch over.  You never know, it's random.

If you are more interested in ensuring 50/50 distribution for every request, then you should probably do it something like this instead (I am assuming your code runs in a single thread. You would have to adjust for multi threading):

```
private static int requestCount = 0;

....

int localCount = requestCount;
requestCount++;
if (localCount % 2 == 0) {
{
    return "PROXY 10.10.10.1:8080; " + "PROXY 10.10.10.2:8080";
}
else
{
    return "PROXY 10.10.10.2:8080; " + "PROXY 10.10.10.1:8080";
}
```

Comment: Hey, I've seen that before :)

Comment: @hoss: hi there. seen what before?

Comment: sorry, a joke from my comment to the question.

Comment: @hoss: ah, I see now.  I guess you hadn't seen my answer when you commented. :)

Comment: yeah I was in the review interface when I made the comment, good answer though. like minds and all.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the awnser, but it's not working in my Proxypac. Are you shore that the proxypac can handle "complex" Java code like this?

Comment: Can't answer that.  Not familiar with proxypac.  I just provided you some valid Java code, and it definitely is not complex.  Perhaps if you provide a bit more context to the lines of code you have already posted, then maybe someone (or me) can help you straighten things up.